# Java android studio null pointer exception

Tags: javascript, java, android, mysql, json

When I click nav order the page is automatically closed. This is my logcat:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.udaya.smartfoodserver, PID: 12671 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference at com.udaya.smartfoodserver.Common.Common.convertCodeToStatus(Common.java:15) at com.udaya.smartfoodserver.OrderStatus$1.populateViewHolder(OrderStatus.java:54) at com.udaya.smartfoodserver.OrderStatus$1.populateViewHolder(OrderStatus.java:49) at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:184)

Comment: add complete logs and relative portion of code

Comment: I think you mean relevant ... not relative.

Comment: What does this have to do with javascript, or mysql, or json.  Or Android Studio?  It is just another NPE bug ... when we can't help you with without seeing the **relevant** code.

Comment: Please put code of "com.udaya.smartfoodserver.Common.Common.convertCodeToStatus"

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WaCr0.jpg

Comment: @Rishikeshpathak https://i.stack.imgur.com/WaCr0.jpg thus is common. Java file

Comment: @Rishikeshpathak please help me

Comment: @user9532828 check for null for string "code" before using equals operator.
if (code != null)
{
//Your code here
}

Comment: @user9532828 Or you can check your string is not null before sending to "convertCodeToStatus" method.

Comment: @Rishikeshpathak order status.java   https://codeshare.io/aJWNV6

Comment: i am a learner plz help me

Comment: @Rishikeshpathak yes it's working but  viewHolder.txtOrderId.setText(adapter.getRef(position).getKey());
                //viewHolder.txtOrderStatus.setText(Common.convertCodeToStatus(model.getStatus()));
                viewHolder.txtOrderAddress.setText(model.getAddress());
                viewHolder.txtOrderPhone.setText(model.getPhone());

Comment: every think is ok but how to get the status.